# Convert Single Quote String to Double Quote String

Tags: python

After running following code, you can get list of five indexes in 'index'

```
import tkinter as tk
OPTIONS = [ "^AEX","^AXJO","^BFX","^BSESN","^MERV","^DJR","^PUT","^OMXC20","^DJA","^DJI","^DJICA","^DJT","^DJU","^DWCF"]
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text='OptionMenus', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')
index = []
def on_button():
    index.clear()
    for i,var in enumerate(o_vars):
        index.append('{}'.format(var.get()))
        index.__str__()
        print('Selected Index {}: {}'.format(i+1, var.get()))
    print()
o_vars = []
for i in range(5):
    var = tk.StringVar(value='- select -')
    o_vars.append(var)
    o = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *OPTIONS)
    o.pack()
b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack(fill='x')
root.mainloop()
```

Based on your selection it looks like:

```
index

Out: ['^BSESN', '^DJI', '^HSI', '^JKII', '^KS11']
```

Now I have to input this string to another code of line at the end of following code, look for the part index[0],index[1]...index[4]

This is not happening. My guess is it must be due to required double quotation.
Any idea on how to achieve it. Tried Replace and all.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import datetime
import requests
import pylab
x =[]
yql_bs_query = []
yql_bs_url = []
data=[]
quote_new =[]
baseurl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
start_date = date(2007, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date.today()
delta = datetime.timedelta(np.timedelta64(end_date - start_date,'D').astype(int) /20)
while start_date <= end_date:
    x.append(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    start_date += delta
for i in range(0,20):
    x[i] = str.format((pd.to_datetime(x[i]) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'"))
    yql_bs_query.append(('select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in (index[0],index[1],index[2],index[3],index[4]) and startDate = ' +x[i]+' and endDate = ' +pd.to_datetime(x[i+1]).strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'") ))`
```

Comment: Its unclear what the exact problem you're having is, but i think its pretty safe to say that the quotes for the string isn't the issue here.

Comment: 'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in (index[0],index[1],index[2],index[3],index[4]) and startDate = ' +x[i]+' and endDate = ' +pd.to_datetime(x[i+1]).strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'") ))`

so I am expecting index[0] should get replaced by its content in above line. you're right as I am not sure what's wrong either and why 'index' list values are not coming in above line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in (index[0],index[1],index[2],index[3],index[4]) and startDate = '
```

Doesn't actually do any replacing of the index values since it just treats this as the literal strings, instead you need to at least apply some string formating on them.

```
'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}) and startDate = '.format(index[0],index[1],index[2],index[3],index[4])
```

Which should at least get you closer to the correct sql string.

Although, you should make sure to use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/1324033) to avoid [bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thank you Sayse!
yql_bs_query.append((('select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(str(index[0]),index[1],index[2],index[3],index[4]) +' and startDate = ' +x[i]+' and endDate = ' +pd.to_datetime(x[i+1]).strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'"))))